# Can't send WhatApp message using Python

Tags: python, whatsapp

I'm using the code sample below. I get it from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/whatsapp-using-python/

I made the necessary changes on the code. Like "changing 'Friend's Name' with an actual friend", "downloading chromedriver", etc.

After running the code, I noticed that it stacks at the line `input_box=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, inp_xpath)))`.

stack->mean : code is waiting until timeout and then giving an error related with timeout issue

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
import time 

# Replace below path with the absolute path 
# to chromedriver in your computer 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/saket/Downloads/chromedriver') 

driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/") 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 600) 

# Replace 'Friend's Name' with the name of your friend 
# or the name of a group 
target = '"Friend\'s Name"'

# Replace the below string with your own message 
string = "Message sent using Python!!!"

x_arg = '//span[contains(@title,' + target + ')]'
group_title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(( 
    By.XPATH, x_arg))) 
group_title.click() 
inp_xpath = '//div[@class="input"][@dir="auto"][@data-tab="1"]'
input_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(( 
    By.XPATH, inp_xpath))) 
for i in range(100): 
    input_box.send_keys(string + Keys.ENTER) 
    time.sleep(1)
```

I want the "string" message to be sent to "target". Could any help me to solve my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One comment of your articles says whatapp changed classes so you could try:
inp_xpath = '//div[@dir="ltr"][@data-tab="1"][@spellcheck="true"]'

Anyway you should try to find out where the xpath comes from/ why its build up like this and check the comment section in your article because there are multiple people with similar problems - one guy stated that this works fine: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/PO1F3VIfmH

Comment: I understand what is wrong with it. Now, I'm trying to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comment made by [sally-zeitler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9548124/sally-zeitler), I have tried a few things.

1. Since `inp_xpath` variable is not same in my chrome browser, I have changed it to correct one.
2. There was a compatibility issue related with chrome browser and chromedriver so I have downloaded the correct one (If you are using Chrome version 76, please download ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.126)
3. Then, it works well :)

Here is the last version of the code sample:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# Replace below path with the absolute path
# to chromedriver in your computer
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/saket/Downloads/chromedriver')

driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 500)
print("#1")
# Replace 'Friend's Name' with the name of your friend
# or the name of a group
#target = '"Friend\'s Name"'
target = '"Your friend name"'
print("#2")
# Replace the below string with your own message
string = '"Message sent using Python!!!"'
print("#3")
x_arg = '//span[contains(@title,' + target + ')]'
group_title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
    By.XPATH, x_arg)))
print("#4")
group_title.click()
print("#5")
inp_xpath = '//div[@class="_3u328 copyable-text selectable-text"]'
input_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
    By.XPATH, inp_xpath)))
print("#6")
for i in range(100):
    print("#7", i)
    input_box.send_keys(string + Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(1)
```